# Programming for the Samsung Galaxy Gear

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, tizen-wearable-sdk

A general question - is there any information available about writing new apps for the Samsung Galaxy Gear?  I know that it runs Android, and has a documented list of features and inputs, but how would one go about integrating an app running on the watch with those on the paired phone ?